# Wordpress custom page by Visual Composer

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using Visual Composer creating some pages in WP and in the middle I have  to do two things

1.create a button with a background img (single image) but with two other small images on both sides.
2.A carousel contains custom scrollbox like this example http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html in each slide.

I try but really don't know how to do that in Visual Composer.
so I want to ask if I can do that individually by html,css,bootstrap then **include it in** my page?  and how to do that then continue to work with VC because it looks some specific things can't be done in VC. I really can not find the solution for weeks, please help me.

Comment: Hi, are you able to code in html, css & JavaScript? Visual Composer has a raw html widget & raw jquery etc.

Comment: Hi so if create a page name History, than I code by html, css, boostrap, can I find the specific History page in the current theme folder and paste those in? it would be easier.